# Firebase Authentication : change requirements and message on password reset through email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Currently, when resetting a password, the firebase requirements provide a very vague and poorly worded message "Strong passwords have at least 6 characters and a mix of letters and numbers". I dislike this message because it never definitively tells the user that they must have a strong password. I would prefer if my message could be a command instead of an enforced suggestion.

Also, I have different requirements to log into my firebase, I require 8 characters and at least one of which must be a special character.

If you have any idea on changing the requirements message or requirements, please let me know.

There are similar posts but they are almost 10 years old and do not provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error code instead and then show your custom error:

```
if (error.code === "weak-password") {
  console.log("Custom error message")
}
```

However this will not chnage the restriction on Firebase end and users  can create passwords with 6 char directly using API

Comment: Please pay attention to the title, I am looking to change how Firebase allows users to reset their passwords with an email.

If it is possible then it may be a setting that I need to change from the Firebase website. It may also be an extension to FirebaseAuth.ResetPassword but I have not seen such settings or extensions.

Comment: @Displayname no it cannot be as explained in the answer. You can deploy a custom reset page to run some custom logic and add the  check for your own validation.